# How to check in if condition whether a File is not empty

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to work with a code where I want it to check if my file is not empty. When I try to do this:

```
void uploadProduct() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      if (image != null) {
        setState(() {
          image = null;
        });
        _formKey.currentState!.reset();
      } else {
        snackBar('Please Pick Image', context);
      }
    } else {
      snackBar('Fields must not be empty', context);
    }
  }
```

What I am trying is to check whether or not if I have the file(image) selected or not, when I don't have any image selected, it should show the snackBar (please pick image) as stated in the else, but it doesn't work.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check for value is null or not

```
if(_image != null)
```

Comment: Can you check the updated post again, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the path of the file, you can use `dart:io`

```
var file = File('the_path_to_the_image');



print(file.lengthSync());
```

now check if length > 0 then file is not empty otherwise file is empty

Comment: Can you check the updated post again, please?

Answer (score 0):

File not being empty isn't very clear. There might be two conditions:

1. File is null
   You can check it by:

```dart
if(_image != null)
```

2. If the file exists but it's empty
   You can check that by:

```dart
final _imageContent = await _image.readAsString();
if(_imagContent.length > 0)
```

Comment: Can you check the updated post again, please?

Comment: Not sure if your validation is coming out to be true or not. Would need more info to reproduce the issue

Comment: https://github.com/Root1-2/V_AID/blob/main/lib/Doctor%20Appoinment/AddDoctor.dart

You can check the whole file here.